# How can I remove Emoji keyboard from iOS8?

Tags: keyboard, ios

I updated my iPad to iOS8, and the Emoji keyboard suddenly appears although I have never set for it. How can I remove that? When I go to Settings:General:Keyboards, I see that Emoji is among the keyboards set, but I can't find a way to remove it.

Comment: Don't you see an Edit button on the list of keyboards?

Comment: @Tomg make that a answer, with few more words or screen shot please.

Comment: Most annoying thing ever for emoticon haters now resolved - thanks @torng

Comment: I don't particularly hate them. I hate the fact that they are added silently by default.

Comment: Especially annoying when you need to switch between languages. (e.g. German<->English, ends up as German->EMOJI->English)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Settings → General → Keyboard → Keyboards. You'll see English and Emoji.

On the top right corner is the word Edit. Press Edit, and then tap the red button followed by Delete to remove the Emoji keyboard.