# How can I delete offensive emojis on my iPhone keyboard

Tags: ios

I would like to be able to delete certain emojis on my keyboard. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there is no way to edit the Apple Emoji keyboard.  You can, however, turn it off, by following the instructions posted at the following question:

[How can I remove Emoji keyboard from iOS8?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145936/how-can-i-remove-emoji-keyboard-from-ios8)

> Settings → General → Keyboard → Keyboards. You'll see English and Emoji.
>
> On the top right corner is the word Edit. Press Edit, and then tap the red button followed by Delete to remove the Emoji keyboard.

Additionally, you may be able to find a 3rd-party Emoji keyboard on the app store that is customizable.

Answer (score 3):

## Custom Keyboard

If you are using an iOS device, such as an iPhone, you may be able to customise the available emojis using a custom keyboard.

iMore review a [few custom keyboards](https://www.imore.com/best-custom-keyboards-ios-8) and others are likely discoverable with the search [`custom iOS keyboard`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=custom+ios+keyboard).

### Tell Apple

Given you find some emojis offensive, I recommend letting Apple know via [Apple's feedback page](https://www.apple.com/feedback). This may be useful cultural information that their designers are not familiar with.